# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1 Models.Hospitals]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`

Tags: asp.net-mvc

When click view in browser I got this error unable to cast object ... in MVC view ,
This is the Hospital Model:

```
public partial class Hospitals
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Hospitals()
        {
            this.hospital_orders = new HashSet<hospital_orders>();
        }
    
        public int hospital_id { get; set; }
        public string hospital_name { get; set; }

     

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<hospital_orders> hospital_orders { get; set; }
    }
```

This is the hospital_orders models :

```
public partial class hospital_orders
    {
        public int order_id { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> hospital_id { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> department_id { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> employee_id { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> status_id { get; set; }
        public string order_details { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> user_id { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> order_date { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> update_date { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> deleted_date { get; set; }
        public string file { get; set; }
    
        public virtual Departments Departments { get; set; }
        public virtual Employees Employees { get; set; }
        public virtual Hospitals Hospitals { get; set; }
        public virtual order_status order_status { get; set; }
        public virtual Users_web Users_web { get; set; }
    }
```

this is the controller create code :

```
public ActionResult Create()
        {
            var hospName = db.Hospitals.ToList();
            List<SelectListItem> listhosp = new List<SelectListItem>();

            foreach (var item in hospName)
            {
                listhosp.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = item.hospital_name, Value = 
                          item.hospital_id.ToString()});
            }
            ViewBag.hospitalname = hospName;

            return View();
        }
```

this is the view code :

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Hospitals.hospital_name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Hospitals.hospital_id,(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>) ViewBag.hospitalname,"Select Hospital", new { @class = "form-control" } )
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.hospital_id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
          
            </div>
        </div>
```

The error appeared on the line with dropdownlistfor , How to solve this error ?

Comment: You shouldn't need to cast a List<> to IEnumerable<> - what happens if you remove the cast?

Comment: @Carl when I removed (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>) I got error in DropDownListFor <hospital_orders> does not contain a definition for DropDownListFor and the best extension method

Comment: This might help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52264750/populate-dropdownlistfor-htmlhelper-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-dropdown using your original cast but a new SelectList rather than a list of SelectListItem in your viewbag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution , the error in Viewbag assignment it should be assigned to list
not to variable like the following :

```
public ActionResult Create()
        {
            var hospName = db.Hospitals.ToList();
            List<SelectListItem> listhosp = new List<SelectListItem>();

            foreach (var item in hospName)
            {
                listhosp.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = item.hospital_name, Value = 
                          item.hospital_id.ToString()});
            }
           // ViewBag.hospitalname = hospName;  error here 

              ViewBag.hospitalname = listhosp ;
            return View();
        }
```